# Change dinamically attributes for Bootstrap Progress-Bar in Angular 5

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code and I want to 2 things:

1. Change the bar color depending on the output of `verifyDifficulty(text1)` (*returns the length of the input text - mocks the difficulty of a password*)

   a.  if `verifyDifficulty(text1)<=3` then bar color=red (progress-easy in css)
   b. if `verifyDifficulty(text1)>3 && verifyDifficulty(text1)<=6` then bar color=yellow (progress-medium in css)
   c. if `verifyDifficulty(text1)>6 && verifyDifficulty(text1)<=9` then bar color=light green (progress-hard in css)
   d.  if `verifyDifficulty(text1)==10 then bar color=dark green` (progress-very-hard in css)
2. modify `aria-valuenow` value to be `verifyDifficulty(text1)*10` but when I try doing property binding I receive this error: ***Can't bind to 'aria-valuenow' since it isn't a known property of 'div'***

My **.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  text1 = '';

  verifyDifficulty(text) {
    const result = text.length;
    return result;
  }
}
```

My **.html**:

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<div class="pb-1">
  <input [(ngModel)]="text1" maxlength="10" placeholder="Text">
</div>
<p>{{verifyDifficulty(text1)}}</p>
<div  *ngIf="verifyDifficulty(text1)<=3" class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-easy" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0"
    aria-valuemax="100" [style.width]="verifyDifficulty(text1)*10+'%'">
    {{verifyDifficulty(text1)*10}}
  </div>
</div>
```

My **.css**:

```
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.progress-bar.progress-easy{
  background-color: #fd0801;
}

.progress-bar.progress-medium{
  background-color: #c1b706;
}

.progress-bar.progress-hard{
  background-color: #8bdb06;
}

.progress-bar.progress-very-hard{
  background-color: #00b006;
}
```

A live demo of this code [is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uuatje)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of your CSS can be handled using `ngClass`. ngClass allows you to apply styles to an element based on conditions, so you might do something like the following for your progress bar:

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-easy" 
     role="progressbar" 
     aria-valuenow="60" 
     aria-valuemin="0"
     aria-valuemax="100"
     [style.width]="verifyDifficulty(text1)*10+'%'"
     [ngClass]="{
        'progress-easy' : verifyDifficulty(text1)<=3,
        'progress-medium' : verifyDifficulty(text1)>3 && verifyDifficulty(text1)<=6,
        'progress-hard' : verifyDifficulty(text1)>6 && verifyDifficulty(text1)<=9,
        'progress-very-hard' :  verifyDifficulty(text1)==10
     }">
     {{verifyDifficulty(text1)*10}}
</div>
```

Although, to keep your template cleaner, I might apply `[ngClass]` with a function, rather than raw conditions in your template. e.g

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-easy" 
     role="progressbar" 
     aria-valuenow="60" 
     aria-valuemin="0"
     aria-valuemax="100"
     [style.width]="verifyDifficulty(text1)*10+'%'"
     [ngClass]="getStyleClass(text1)">
     {{verifyDifficulty(text1)*10}}
</div>
```

Where `getStyleClass(text1)` is a function in your component that returns the class based on input.

Now, for your `aria` issue, first, to apply an attribute in Angular, you use the `attr` binding, as already mentioned, so in your case:

```
[attr.aria-valuenow]="whatever"
```

The alternative, and perhaps better, depending on your school of thought, is to use `Renderer2` to apply the aria dynamically, as such, you need to inject it in your component, and make your progress bar a `ViewChild`.

```
@ViewChild('progressBar') progressBar: ElementRef;

constructor(private renderer2: Renderer2) { }
```

Now your template becomes:

```
<div #progressBar class="progress-bar progress-easy" 
     role="progressbar" 
     aria-valuenow="60" 
     aria-valuemin="0"
     aria-valuemax="100"
     [style.width]="verifyDifficulty(text1)*10+'%'"
     [ngClass]="getStyleClass(text1)">
     {{verifyDifficulty(text1)*10}}
</div>
```

Note the additions of `#progressBar` - This marks the element as a viewchild, under that reference.

Now, when you need to change your aria value, you can do it dynamically with:

```
this.renderer2.setAttribute(this.progressBar.nativeElement, 'aria-valuenow', 'whatever value');
```

Job's a good'un!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`attr.aria-valuenow="60"`

or

`[attr.aria-valuenow]="60"`